# How to put a button on top of a specific area in an image

Tags: android

I have been trying to put a button on top of an image in a specific area. So, the button will stick to the specific area in the image even if the device is rotated or in different screen sizes.

So far i have tried a couple of things but none of them seems working as when i rotate the device then the button moves to another area.

**1.** I tried to draw a rectangle using specific coordinates but on device rotation the rectangle moves to another area. Below is the code:

```
ArrayList<Rect> mAreas = new ArrayList<>();
mAreas.add(new Rect(0,0,200,200));
mAreas.add(new Rect(300,0, 500, 300));

mImageView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    for (final Rect cRect : mAreas) {
        if (cRect.contains(event.getX(), event.getY())) {
        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "AREA TOUCHED!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
    }
});
```

**2.** also tried with constraintlayout and again the button moves to another place:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imgvw4"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:src="@drawable/cartoon"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"/>
    <Button
    android:text="Button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/button_4"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/imgvw4"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/imgvw4"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/imgvw4"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/imgvw4"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.25"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias ="0.5"  />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

[image: Screen shot- when using constraintLayout]

How do i solve it? Lets say in the below image-  in want to have a button which will be on top of the eyes. Please help me with some guidelines or references.

[image: given image]

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use Linear Layout or Relative Layout.
In Linear Layout make the orientation Vertical and put the button above and then the image or u can use relative layout and then add the attribute layout_alignParentTop =true in the button. The button will remain at the top.
Hope this solves ur question.

Comment: I need the button to stick to an specific area on top of the image even if device is rotated or in different screen sizes.